# Amazon EC2 CLI Connection Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On running the command `aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id instance_id` I am constantly getting

`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"`

On checking [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) link I can see that the region endpoint is different for EC2.

How do I change the endpoint using the `aws configure` command?

Comment: Where are you running this command? On a EC2 machine? Can you `ping ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default end point with `--endpoint-url`:

From the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)

> --endpoint-url (string)
>
> Override command's default URL with the given URL.

Comment: I did. I also am not hitting the proper ec2 endpoint, the one that I want but still getting the error:

`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"`

Am I missing something else here?

Comment: is the machine that you are using able to resolve and connect to `ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`, can you try `nc -v ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com 443` and see what it reports?

Comment: found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
 outif en0
 src 192.168.1.91 port 63804
 dst 176.32.118.30 port 443
 rank info not available
 TCP aux info available

Connection to ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!

Comment: really weird, the error indicates that the cli is not able to connect to this, but you machine can indeed connect to it.. any kind of firewall based stuff that might only block the aws cli? If not, not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Did I configure it wrong? I also dont get it. It should ideally work fine.

Comment: If possible, try it on a different network (eg home vs work) or on a different computer.